# How do i configure html2pdf to render properly

Tags: html2pdf

[pic of pdf file being made](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JenTp.png)  I am trying to insert a number of graphs into a pdf using html2pdf but its cutting off some charts and weird spacing on top

More code cut off so curly brackets may not make scense

CDN liknk are also on top

```
      <script>
               for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++){

                        //Insert data into chart (cant make public)

                        // create the chart
                        var chart = anychart.column();


                        // add data
                        chart.data(data[i]);
                        chart.pointWidth(50);
                        chart.barsPadding(-1);
                        chart.minPointLength(0);


                        // draw
                        let label = '<br><label>'+trap+'</label><br>'
                        let elem = `<div id="container-${i}" style="width:80%;"></div>`
                        let labElm = label + elem
                        document.getElementById("wrapper").innerHTML += labElm;
                        chart.container(`container-${i}`);
                        
                        chart.draw();
                        

              }
               
                                                    
                }
            });

        });
        


    </script>

<div id="container" style="width:100%;">
    <div id="wrapper"></div>
</div>

<button id="download-pdf">Download PDF</button>

<script>
      document.getElementById("download-pdf").addEventL[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vuIyy.png)istener("click", () => {
        html2pdf().from(document.getElementById('wrapper')).save();
      });
</script>
```